# Disable substring filename completion in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

In `zsh`, when I type beginning of a filename, and autocomplete with tab:

```
$ ls gs<tab>
```

if there is no match starting with `gs`, I might get:

```
$ ls logs
```

Far from being useful, I find this feature actually harmful. I want to
know that there is no match in current dir (perhaps I entered the wrong
dir mistakenly).

To add insult to injury, the autocompleted/autocorrected filename does
not exist either (there is a file `bootlogs`, but no file `logs`)

How can I disable this "feature" ?
I tried adding following options into my .zshrc, but that did not help:

```
unsetopt correct
unsetopt correct_all
```

I have also removed `_correct` and `_approximate` from the completer:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete
```

and here is the `matcher-list` line:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}' 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=* l:|=*'
```

I am using `zsh 4.3.17`, without any included framework (such as oh-my-zsh).

Comment: Fix the `matcher-list` style that you set then, if you use `r` or `l` with some vague values it happens.

Comment: @llua - thatnks. Rremoving the `matcher-list` line seems to do the trick.

Comment: Since you're pressing Tab, that's a completion setting, not related to autocorrect. I think there's an option for that in `compinstall`, if you don't want to figure out what value of `matcher-list` would suit you.

Comment: @Gilles - how come completion works, even if I remove the whole `matcher-list` line? It seems to have same effect as leaving only `zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list ''`. Is that the default setting?

Comment: @400theCat Yes: the completion code does `zstyle -a ":completion:${curcontext}:" matcher-list _matchers || _matchers=( '' )`